# JAVA: Basic java logic

Tags: java

I have been working with java just a little, but there is these small logic things that I seem to never understand and I'll give an example right away.
I currently have this code:

```
class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ST<String, Integer> st;
    st = new ST<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; !StdIn.isEmpty(); i++) {
        String key = StdIn.readString();
        st.put(key, i);
    }

    st.put("P", 5); // Put method

    for (String s : st.keys()) {
        StdOut.println(s + " " + st.get(s));
    }

  }
}
```

So what it does is that it creates a Symbol Table and inserts some data to it from a file provided. As you can see, I have a put method which inserts the value 5 on key "P". I want to create a method for this just for the sake of practice. 
So what I do is:

```
public static void addValue() {
    st.put("P", 5);
}
```

and call that method instead of the "put" method in my code. However I can't compile this, since the method "addValue" doesn't know the variable `st`.

I then thought to put these two lines:

```
ST<String, Integer> st;
st = new ST<String, Integer>();
```

into the class constructor, but that didn't make it. Can someone please explain some logic behind this because theres clearly something I'm missing. How can I split this code into methods in a nice way just for the sake of practice? + If anyone knows of a good place to just read about logic like this, I'll be enourmously appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by reading about variable scope: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: you need to add the method `addValue()` to the `ST` class.  Then, you can simply call `this.put("P", 5);` inside `addValue(..)` instead of `st.put(..);` - also, in the main method, you can do `ST.addValue();` to invoke it - OR pass it as a variable like @DavidZhou indicates below :)

Comment: You need a static field. Currently you only have variables within methods

Comment: Just pass it via parameters `public static void addValue(ST st)`, and call it like `addValue(st)`

Comment: Thanks all, the ST class is from a library that I have no control over btw

Comment: The declaration of `st` lacks the `static` attribute, but the method `addValue` *is* `static`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `st` is only known to the main method because you declared it there. To allow access from other methods you should create a class member. Here is the class that should do what you want:

```
class test {

    private static ST<String, Integer> st;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        st = new ST<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; !StdIn.isEmpty(); i++) {
            String key = StdIn.readString();
            st.put(key, i);
        }

        addValue();

        for (String s : st.keys()) {
            StdOut.println(s + " " + st.get(s));
        }

    }

    public static void addValue() {
        st.put("P", 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a really good point, this is something I am looking for as well. I have now tried different kind of way to achieve what I want and it's a really great way to learn the logic. Thanks!

Comment: oh and btw, in order for this to help, the private field "ST" has to be static. I am not sure why though?

Comment: In order to access a class variable inside a static method, this variable has to be static as well. This means there is only one "version" of this variable for all instances of this class. If for example object A adds an entry into `st` then object B can "see" this. To avoid a static variable you should pass necessary variables as a method argument like David Zhou suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can either add it as a class member

```
class test {

    private static ST<String, Integer> st;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         st = new ST<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; !StdIn.isEmpty(); i++) {
            String key = StdIn.readString();
            st.put(key, i);
        }

        addValue();

        for (String s : st.keys()) {
            StdOut.println(s + " " + st.get(s));
        }

    }

    public static void addValue() {
        st.put("P", 5);
    }
}
```

or pass it in as a variable

```
public static void addValue(ST<String, Integer> st) {
    st.put("P", 5);
}
```

Then from your main method you can just call

```
addValue(st);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. Class names should be upper case, in this case `Test` (convention)
2. The class with the main method should be public (convention)
3. `ST` is not part of Java (in your comments you write its part of a library, this information should be part of the question), same for `StdIn` and `StdOut`.
4. Your class is in the default package, thats ok for a test though.

To actually solve your question, there are a couple of solutions. BlithE already showed you one, the other is mentioned by David Zhou in a comment:

```
// missing ST StdIn and StdOut, they probably need too be imported
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ST<String, Integer> st;
        st = new ST<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; !StdIn.isEmpty(); i++) {
            String key = StdIn.readString();
            st.put(key, i);
        }

        addValue(st);

        for (String s : st.keys()) {
            StdOut.println(s + " " + st.get(s));
        }

    }

    public static void addValue(ST<String, Integer> st) {
        st.put("P", 5);
    }
}
```